# Hosting Video's on Youtube or a service like youtube with HTML5 / FLASH switching

Tags: web-hosting, html5, video, youtube

We have 1000's of small product videos currently being played through a Flash player.

We want to make this product videos work on apple devices.

It's my understanding that Youtube auto switches from flash to HTML5 depending on the device.

I thought YouTube allows you to have a business account and use their "Chromeless" player to show your videos unbranded. But looking they don't seem to offer that service.

Are there any other services that we can upload a file format to, have complete control over the player and have it select the correct file format for the device automagically?

Preferably we would only like the videos accessible if called from the website, not just for general view like youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a paid-for Vimeo account does just this - a service like Vimeo is in my opinion more favorable than Youtube as any shares/links to your video will count towards the PR or *your* site and not that of Youtube

https://vimeo.com/plus

Answer (score 1):

Awhile back I was looking into this and as Jack stated there is Vimeo but I was surprised when someone mentioned [Photobucket](http://beta.photobucket.com/). I know how odd it sounds, but I could see Photobucket possibly working with video.  You also could do your own development with [Video.js](http://videojs.com/) but I did see you were looking for an "upload" option.  Hope this helps.